# Implement service provider using OpenSAML

Tags: java, saml-2.0, openam, opensaml

I have implemented `idp` using `OpenAM`. Now i have to implement `sp`. I tired using fedlet but couldn't integrate with my existing app. So, i am now trying to write `sp` from scratch to implement `SSO`. Can anyone provide steps to implement `sp` using `OpenSAML`?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you define a SP in OpenAM without the fedlet? If you want to use OpenSAML for it, I have a book, [A Guide to OpenSAML](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/a-guide-to-opensamlv3.html), that introduces SAML and the OpenSAML library. I also have lots of examples [here](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/2011/01/redirect-with-authnrequest.html) on my blog.

Comment: Ok i am little confused here. If i define `SP` in `OpenAM` where will  the authentication takes place? I have `LDAP server(with user datastore)` set up in `IDP`. It would be great if the authentication takes place in `IDP` and redirect to my existing app?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a java-based WebApp then using Spring Security SAML extension is quite simple to integrate.